# Can't order by or select only this one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do an extremely simple sql query but am running into an issue with this one column named Group. The Group column is not a key.

The following two statements fail in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Lib.Stuff st
LEFT JOIN Lib.StuffOptions sto
on st.OptionId=sto.id
order by pa.Group desc, pa.Level
```

```
SELECT st.LongName,
       st.Group,
       sto.Name
FROM Lib.Stuff st
LEFT JOIN Lib.StuffOptions sto
on st.OptionId=sto.id
```

Both calls fail with the same error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword Group`. I can use literally any other column name of Stuff and it works. But only for Group it fails.

Comment: st.[Group] ... try to avoid reserved words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Group` is a reserved keyword, you need to use square brackets to escape it.

```
SELECT st.LongName,
       st.[Group],
       sto.Name
FROM Lib.Stuff st
LEFT JOIN Lib.StuffOptions sto
on st.OptionId=sto.id
```

Better to avoid using reserved keywords as identifiers